# Integration of $\int \sqrt[3]{\sin x \cos x} \text{ }dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I was working on a problem of integration and need a bit of help. The problem is shown below

$$\int \sqrt[3]{\sin x \cos x} \text{ }dx$$

So I tried substitution and took $\sqrt[3]{\sin x}=t$ so differentiating both sides we get $\frac{\cos x}{3 {(\sin x)}^{2/3}} = \frac{dt}{dx}$. Now ${(\sin x)}^{2/3}$ can be written as $t^{\frac{2}{3}}$ but how do I deal with $\cos x dx$ as we have $\sqrt[3]{\cos x}$ to replace.

Will deeply appreciate the help on this one.

Comment: $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

Comment: Or $\sin x\cdot\cos x = \frac12\sin 2x$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196789/solve-int-frac1-sin-frac12x-cos-frac72xdx/2196842#2196842

Comment: The integral of $(\sin x)^{1/3}$ is in terms of the hypergeometric function. To me it seems your integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Are you sure there are no bounds?

Comment: Could the problem be simply $\int \sqrt[3]{\sin( x)} \cos (x) \,dx$ ?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the integral can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: @DavidH. Which one ? Just curious. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  $\int_{0}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\sqrt[3]{\sin{\left(\omega\right)}}=\frac32\int_{0}^{\sqrt[3]{\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}$

Answer (score 3):

As said in comments, the integral is in terms of hypergeometric function. Without any simplification, what is produced by a CAS is 
$$I(x)=\int \sqrt[3]{\sin (x)
   \cos (x)} \,dx=\frac{3}{4} \sqrt[3]{\cos ^2(x)}\sqrt[3]{\sin (x)
   \cos (x)} \tan (x) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};\sin ^2(x)\right) $$

The only solution I can see is a series expansion around $x=0$ which would give for the integrand
$$x^{\frac 13} \left(1-\frac{2 x^2}{9}-\frac{2 x^4}{405}-\frac{212 x^6}{76545}-\frac{382
   x^8}{492075}-\frac{81412 x^{10}}{341007975}-\frac{64322396
   x^{12}}{837856594575}+O\left(x^{14}\right)\right)$$

Integrating termwise, this would give
$$I(x)\sim x^{\frac 43} \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{x^2}{15}-\frac{x^4}{1080}-\frac{106 x^6}{280665}-\frac{191
   x^8}{2296350}-\frac{40706 x^{10}}{1932378525}-\frac{16080599
   x^{12}}{2792855315250}+O\left(x^{14}\right) \right)$$
Because of the symmetry, we only need to focus for the range $0 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 2$. For these bounds, numerical integration would give $1.02670$ while the above truncated series would lead to $1.03694$ (which, I agree, is far away to be fantastic).

For smaller values of the upper bound, the results do not look too bad
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 t & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.1 & 0.034781 & 0.034781 \\
 0.2 & 0.087409 & 0.087409 \\
 0.3 & 0.149416 & 0.149416 \\
 0.4 & 0.217891 & 0.217891 \\
 0.5 & 0.290998 & 0.290998 \\
 0.6 & 0.367329 & 0.367329 \\
 0.7 & 0.445677 & 0.445677 \\
 0.8 & 0.524937 & 0.524936 \\
 0.9 & 0.604041 & 0.604041 \\
 1.0 & 0.681920 & 0.681917 \\
 1.1 & 0.757449 & 0.757438 \\
 1.2 & 0.829400 & 0.829351 \\
 1.3 & 0.896352 & 0.896156 \\
 1.4 & 0.956565 & 0.955807 \\
 1.5 & 1.007779 & 1.004739
\end{array}
\right)$$

Assuming $0 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 2$
$$I(x)=\frac{3}{4} \sin ^{\frac{4}{3}}(x) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};\sin ^2(x)\right)$$ which does not help at all since $\int \sin ^{2 n+\frac{4}{3}}(x)\,dx$ already involves the gaussian hypergeometric function.